# Import nouislider with webpack on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, nouislider

I'm trying to implement a nouislider on Rails. I installed it with Yarn and my package.json confirms this: "nouislider": "^11.1.0".

Unfortunatly I got this error on the chrome console :

*Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined at Object. (slider2.js:12)*

here is my app/javascript/packs/application.js :

```
import "nouislider";
import '../components/slider2';
```

(where slider2.js is my noUiSlider script)

What is wrong with this importation? Why does slider2.js don't understand what is noUislider?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import noUiSlider from "nouislider";
```

Also going to a assume you have a file in the correct place for your second line.